# NPM - Can't complete Browserify installation because acorn5-object-spread

Tags: node.js, npm, browserify

I have a system that when deploying tries to install **browserify**, but the installation is not completed by an HTTP 404 corresponding to the **acorn5-object-spread** plugin, as seen in the following console extract (node 0.10.42 and npm 1.3.6):

```
npm http 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/browserify/acorn5-object-spread
npm ERR! TypeError: Cannot read property 'latest' of undefined
npm ERR!     at next (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:687:35)
npm ERR!     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:675:5
npm ERR!     at saved (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/get.js:148:7)
npm ERR!     at /usr/lib/node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js:133:7
npm ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:108:15)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "browserify" "minifyify" "jstify" "grunt"
npm ERR! cwd /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/SATI-Deploy frontend to localhost/workspace
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.42
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.6
npm ERR! type non_object_property_load
```

If this can not be corrected, Could the **acorn5-object-spread** plugin be omitted or excluded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `@browserify/acorn5-object-spread` dependency is published as a scoped package. You're using a very very **very** old version of node and npm—npm v1 does not support scoped packages.

The best thing to do would be to upgrade your node and npm versions by downloading the latest stable or LTS version from https://nodejs.org or by running `npm install --global npm@2`. (I think npm v2 already supports scoped packages, but newer versions are even better.)

If that is not an option, you can downgrade your browserify dependency to v14.x or lower, since those do not depend on the `acorn5-object-spread` package.

```
// package.json:
"browserify": "^14.0.0"
```

Comment: I ran `npm install --global npm@2` (this updated my npm to 2.15.12) and this prevented the error of the **acorn5-object-spread**. But now I'm getting `npm ERR! peerinvalid The package grunt@1.0.1 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!` Could this be because my node is 0.10.42 still?

Comment: Nevermind, I updated my nvm to npm@3 and the `peerinvalid` errors are now just warns.